# Laravel 5.4, file upload timing out

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I have a form that uploads a photo file to storage and the path to a db. 
I get the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php
```

Below is my current code.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Laravel 5.4.

**Controller logic**

```php
public function create(request $request) {

$validatedData = $request->validate([
  'name' => 'required|min:2',
  'roast' => 'required|min:2',
  'origin' => 'required|min:2',
  'price' => 'required',
  'photo' => 'required|file|image'

]);

$new = new product;
$name = $new->create();
session()->flash("message", "$name was created");
return back();
}
```

---

**Model Logic**

```php
public function create() {

$file = request()->file('photo');
$extension = $file->extension();
$name = request('name').request('roast').'.'.$extension;
$path = $file->storeAs('public/images',$name);

  product::create([
  'name' => request('name'),
  'roast' => request('roast'),
  'origin' => request('origin'),
  'photo' => $path,
  'price' => request('price'),
  'stock' => 0
]);

return request('name');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a server configuration issue not a **Laravel** issue just increase the **max_execution_time** and **max_input_time**  in your php.ini .

Answer (score 1):

For increase execution time use it

```
public function create(request $request) 
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    // other code
```

It is increase execution time to 300 seconds

Comment: Thought this would solve it, but still times out. Its a code issue.

Comment: change execution time more

Answer (score 0):

Check this if you want to store in public directory.

```
 

       if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->image;
            $image->move('uploads', $image->getClientOriginalName());
        }

        Product::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'image' => $request->image->getClientOriginalName()
        ]);
```

Also check server configurations in your case.